# Why does the wm_concat not work here?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-aggregation, wm-concat

I have this query :

```
(SELECT OBJECT_ID from cr_object_group_entries_vw where object_group_id IN
    (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE(CR_FN_SPLIT_STRING('28,56',','))))
```

that returns :

[image]

But when I do :

```
SELECT wm_concat(object_id) FROM
    (SELECT OBJECT_ID from cr_object_group_entries_vw where object_group_id IN
        (SELECT ITEM FROM TABLE(CR_FN_SPLIT_STRING('28,56',','))))
```

I get a blank result... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You must avoid `wm_concat` function because it is undocumented and discovered as workaround at Oracle 8i times.

Since times of old method with custom aggregate function as discovered by Tom Kyte [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336) there are some new workarounds, showed at examples below.

All of them reproduced in [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5eef8/2).

Workaround 1 - LISTAGG function, works in 11g:

```
select listagg(object_id,',') within group (order by rownum) id_string
from cr_object_group_entries_vw
```

Workaround 2 - SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, works since 10g:

```
select id_string from (
  select rn, substr(sys_connect_by_path(object_id, ','),2) id_string
  from (select object_id, rownum rn from cr_object_group_entries_vw)
  start with rn = 1
  connect by prior rn + 1 = rn
  order by rn desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

Workaround 3 - XMLAGG, works since 10g:

```
select replace(
         replace(
           replace(
             xmlagg(xmlelement("x",object_id)).getStringVal(),
             '</x><x>',
             ','
           ),
           '<x>',
           ''
         ),
         '</x>',
         ''
       ) id_string
from cr_object_group_entries_vw
```

P.S. I didn't know exactly in which Oracle versions `sys_connect_by_path` and `xmlagg` was introduced, but both works well on 10.2.0.4.0

Comment: `wm_concat` is no more included with `12c.

Answer (score 6):

In case you're on 11g try [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) instead of `wm_concat` for starters.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this post regarding `wm_concat` and thought to share some information.

Any application which has had been relying on `wm_concat` function will not work once upgraded to `12c`. Since, it has been removed from the latest 12c version. See [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SELECT object_name
  2  FROM dba_objects
  3  WHERE owner='WMSYS'
  4  AND object_name LIKE 'WM\_%' ESCAPE '\';

OBJECT_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_REPLICATION_INFO
WM_RDIFF
WM_PERIOD
WM_PERIOD
WM_OVERLAPS
WM_MEETS
WM_LESSTHAN
WM_LDIFF
WM_INTERSECTION
WM_INSTALLATION
WM_GREATERTHAN
WM_EVENTS_INFO
WM_ERROR
WM_ERROR
WM_EQUALS
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_CONTAINS
WM_COMPRESS_BATCH_SIZES
WM_COMPRESSIBLE_TABLES

20 rows selected.
```

You will receive an “**invalid identifier**” error:

```
SQL> SELECT banner FROM v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp;
SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
```

Therefore, there is no point relying on an **undocumented feature** which is no more made available in latest versions.

For alternate solutions, please see **[Oracle String Aggregation Techniques](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)**

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be doing anything wrong. With a dummy table function to return the data you showed, `wm_concat` worked for me:

```
select wm_concat(object_id) from
    (select object_id from cr_object_group_entries_vw where object_group_id in
        (select item from table(cr_fn_split_string('28,56',','))))
/

WM_CONCAT(OBJECT_ID)                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
36,1,11,121,13,14,17,18,2,24,3,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,44,6,7,8,81
```

You've tagged the question as [11g]; as @beherenow said, if you can you should use the supported `lisgagg` over the unsupported `wm_concat`, though it's only available from 11gR2 I think:

```
select listagg(object_id, ',') within group (order by object_id)
from cr_object_group_entries_vw
where object_group_id in
    (select item from table(cr_fn_split_string('28,56',',')))
/

LISTAGG(OBJECT_ID,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYOBJECT_ID)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,11,121,13,14,17,18,2,24,3,32,33,34,35,36,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,44,6,7,8,81
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d57bf/1) (for `listagg` only, since it doesn't support `wm_concat` - maybe your instance doesn't either, but then it should error?)

Comment: Unfortunately LISTAGG gives the same result, I just forgot to mention that. wm_concat also works for me when using dummy data, yet on the real data above both LIST AGG and wm_concat fail.

Comment: @MuhammadA - interesting. Sounds like something in your table function is confusing things, or more likely (perhaps) in your view, though I can't immediately see how. Can you see the same effect if you replace the view (I assume `cr_object_group_entries` is a view from the name) with the base tables?

Comment: I have been trying this - SELECT wm_concat(item) FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE (CR_FN_SPLIT_STRING('1,2,12,3,4,12,3',','))) which first splits then joins the same list and its working fine, but with the view it is not, even though when I just run the view subquery (screenshot above) its returning a result you would assume could later be joined.

Comment: @MuhammadA - without being able to reproduce the effect it's hard to offer any further advice. The only thing that comes to mind to try is to add a `/*+ MATERIALIZE */ hint to the select from the view, but grasping at straws a bit. This sounds like a bug to me, you might be better off raising an SR with Oracle?