# I want the output without using the case or decode in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation, listagg

```
 STUD_ID SUBJECT              GRADE

 1       math                 a
 1       english              b
 1       computer             c
 2       math                 c
 2       lang                 a
 3       phys                 a
 3       chem                 b
```

Output should be like this:

```
  stud_id   grades
    1       a,b,c
    2       c,a
    3       a,b
```

Comment: you need to include some CREATE and INSERT statements, and a better idea as to what you want as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Oracle version 11g and up, you could simply use **LISTAGG** string aggregation function.

For example,

```
*SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

For other version specific solution, please see the examples demonstrated [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

**NOTE** Remember, DO NOT use `wm_concat`, it was undocumented in prior 12c versions, and it is not supported in 12c. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758117/3989608) for more details.

**UPDATE** On OP's request regarding solution for 10g.

There are two ways as mentioned in Tim Hall's article:

- **COLLECT** function in **Oracle 10g**

For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
                                          p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
END tab_to_string;
/
```

- **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions in **Oracle 9i** and up

For example,

```
SELECT deptno,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
FROM   (SELECT deptno,
               ename,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
GROUP BY deptno
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND deptno = PRIOR deptno
START WITH curr = 1;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: realy appreciate with ur answer..im using 10g do u have ny idea how to do it on 10g...

Comment: @Sam Ok, see my updated answer. I have added few examples. Please mark it answered, would help others as well.