# Comma separated column without XML path

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, string-aggregation

I have table like below

```
ID Name
1  a
1  b
1  c
2  d
2  e
3  f
```

I would like to get result as

```
ID Name
1  a,b,c
2  d,e
3  f
```

I don't want to use any `XMLPATH` or `coalesce` functions.
Just in simple SQL query I need to get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on **`Oracle 10g`** version, you cannot use **`LISTAGG`**. It was introduced in **`11g`**.

And please **DON'T** use **WM_CONCAT** as it is an **undocumented feature**, and has been removed from the latest release. See [Why does the wm_concat not work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674927/why-does-the-wm-concat-not-work-here/28758117#28758117)

For 10g, you have following string aggregation techniques:

1. **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH**
2. User-defined function **STRAGG** as demonstrated by Tom Kyte here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402
3. **COLLECT** function in **PL/SQL**

Following is a pure SQL method using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` functions available since 9i:

```
SQL> column emp_list format a50
SQL> SELECT deptno,
  2         LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
  3         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cur),',') AS emp_list
  4  FROM   (SELECT deptno,
  5                 ename,
  6                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) AS cur,
  7                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS prev
  8          FROM   emp)
  9  GROUP BY deptno
 10  CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR cur AND deptno = PRIOR deptno
 11  START WITH cur = 1;

    DEPTNO EMP_LIST
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 10 you can use the inofficial function WM_CONCAT for this. In later versions you'd use LISTAGG.

```
select id, wm_concat(name)
from mytable
group by id;
```

Comment: Don't use `WM_CONCAT` since it is undocumented, and moreover it has been removed from the latest release. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28758117/3989608

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B: Undocumented is not the problem, the syntax is easy: `WM_CONCAT([DISTINCT] column_name)`. The problem is, as I did mention, that it is inofficial. So it may not be avaliable in a certain installation. The only alternative I know of is to write a custom aggregation function, but well, you can as well use WM_CONCAT and only write a custom WM_CONCAT when you get in a situation where the function is lacking.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B: Ah, I just read your answer. So there *are* alternatives :-)

Comment: I would allow the developers to use it only in test environment as a one time activity. Never in production. You know the reply from the Oracle Support `Oh!, wm_concat... We don't support it`