# WM_CONCAT duplicates removal

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-aggregation, wm-concat

I have a table like below.

```
   colA       colB
   12345      NHS,CDE,BCD
   12345      NHS,ABC,DEF
```

Need to display the data in below format

```
   colA       colB
   12345      NHS,ABC,BCD,CDE,DEF
```

I need generalized solution to remove the duplicate NHS, which comes first, and then put the remaining words in alphabetical order.

Comment: Processing denormalized data to produce denormalized data? Hopefully this is a one time only job. If you actually need this you might consider using arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never use **WM_CONCAT** since it is undocumented and is no more available in the latest version 12c. See [Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/) and [Why does the wm_concat not work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674927/why-does-the-wm-concat-not-work-here/28758117#28758117)

Since you are on 11g, you could use **LISTAGG**.

The below query does following things:

1. [**Split the comma delimited string into rows**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/).
2. Apply string aggregation using **LISTAGG**.
3. **CASE** expression to handle the custom ordering.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2      SELECT 12345 colA, 'NHS,CDE,BCD' colB FROM dual UNION ALL
  3      SELECT 12345 colA, 'NHS,ABC,DEF' colB FROM dual
  4      )
  5  SELECT cola,
  6    listagg(colb, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
  7  ORDER BY
  8    CASE colb
  9      WHEN 'NHS'
 10      THEN 1
 11      ELSE 2
 12    END, colb) colb
 13  FROM
 14    (SELECT DISTINCT cola,
 15      trim(regexp_substr(colb, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) colb
 16    FROM DATA
 17      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(colb, ',')+1
 18    ORDER BY colb
 19    )
 20  GROUP BY cola
 21  /

      COLA COLB
---------- ------------------------------
     12345 NHS,ABC,BCD,CDE,DEF
```

**Edit** As @AlexPoole pointed out, explicit ordering was missing and previous query(see edit history) relied on the distinct ordering of the values.

Comment: Being picky, I'd prefer to see your order by include the actual `colb` value as well as the case: `(ORDER BY CASE colb WHEN 'NHS' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, colb)` It works now but relies on `distinct` ordering the values, and who knows if that might change one day *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Good point, thanks. Though the ORDER BY in the inline view won't make much difference here.

Comment: No, I agree, I only meant in the listagg's order-by clause.

Comment: thanks Lalit and Alex for the clarifications. btw is there any way to remove NHS from order by, so that I can write a generalized query.

Comment: @RaghavaCh, use SUBSTR to extract the first vaue, retain it, aggregate only the other values, finally append them. To understand, execute each subquery in the above solution one by one starting from the innermost one. Look at the resultset, you will get an idea how to generalize the query.

Comment: What if I am using oracle 10g? LISTAGG does not work in 10g. Any solution?

Comment: @Yubaraj You do it like this https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#row_number

Comment: @LalitKumarB I will look on this. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT col1,wm_concat(col2) AS col2 FROM test1 GROUP BY col1
  ) , t1 AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT col1, regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) names
  FROM t
    CONNECT BY rownum <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(col2, '[^,]'))+1
  ORDER BY names
  )
SELECT col1,wm_concat(names) AS names FROM t1 GROUP BY col1
```