# Getting SQL Error: ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, wm-concat

Why do i get this error in a clone db from the origins?

```
Getting SQL Error: ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
```

I am using Oracle 11gR2. The original database still run successfully.

```
BANNER                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production              
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                                           
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production                                                         
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                          
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Comment: You are on 11gR2.  Why are you using the undocumented (and hence unsupported) WM_CONCAT function rather than [LISTAGG()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) ???

Comment: The whole script is large and difficult to replace with listagg :(

Comment: Please post the result of `select banner from v$version`. Are you sure you are on `11g`? `WM_CONCAT` has been removed from `12c` though. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28758117/3989608 and [Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

Comment: What process did you use to clone the database?

Comment: My Oracle:

`BANNER                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production              
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                                           
CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production                                                         
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                          
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production`

Comment: Can you login as `SYSTEM` and check if the following `SELECT object_name
    FROM dba_objects
    WHERE owner='WMSYS'
    AND object_name LIKE 'WM\_%' ESCAPE '\';`

Comment: Yes, it result **no rows selected**.
I think i found the problem because im using Oracle XE

Comment: It means whoever installed Oracle, opted not to install it. WMSYS account is used for Oracle Workspace Manager which is an optional feature.

Comment: What happens if you log in as `sys` and then run `grant execute on wmsys.wm_concat to public`?

Comment: I try run `grant execute on wmsys.wm_concat to public` in sqlplus system but a only a blank line shown