# How to concatenate multiple rows order by sequence in Oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, string-aggregation, wm-concat

If I have a data like this:

```
GROUP  |  SEQUENCE  |  COMMAND
------------------------------
ONE    |     3      |  <message2>MESSAGE</message2>
ONE    |     1      |  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
ONE    |     2      |  <message1>MESSAGE</message1>
TWO    |     2      |  <message2>MESSAGE</message2>
TWO    |     1      |  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
........
TWO    |    10      |  <message9>MESSAGE</message9>
```

How can I concatenate the command to be like this:

```
GROUP  |  COMMAND
-----------------
ONE    |  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>,<message1>MESSAGE</message1>,<message2>MESSAGE</message2>
TWO    |  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>,<message1>MESSAGE</message1>, .. ,<message9>MESSAGE</message9>
```

I used this query below but the command column is not in order according to their sequence number:

```
SELECT GROUP, WM_CONCAT(COMMAND) AS COMMAND
     FROM (SELECT GROUP, SEQUENCE, COMMAND FROM TBL ORDER BY SEQUENCE)
     GROUP BY GROUP

//AND THIS

SELECT GROUP, WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT COMMAND) AS COMMAND
 FROM (SELECT GROUP, SEQUENCE, COMMAND FROM TBL ORDER BY SEQUENCE)
 GROUP BY GROUP
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `WM_CONCAT`. Read [Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

See this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758117/3989608.

It is undocumented, and any application which relies on `WM_CONCAT` will not work once upgraded to `12c` because it has been removed from the latest 12c version.

There are many ways of doing **string-aggregation**, depending on the **database version**. See few examples below:

**11gR2**

Use `LIASTAGG`:

```
SQL> SELECT grp,
  2    listagg(command, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
  3  ORDER BY seq) command
  4  FROM t
  5  GROUP BY grp;

GRP COMMAND
--- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ONE <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>,<message1>MESSAGE</message1>,<message2>MESSAGE</message2>
TWO <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>,<message2>MESSAGE</message2>,<message9>MESSAGE</message9>

SQL>
```

**9i and up**

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

```
SQL> SELECT grp,
  2         LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(command,','))
  3         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY seq),',') command
  4  FROM   (SELECT grp,
  5                 command,
  6                 seq,
  7                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY seq) AS curr,
  8                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY seq) -1 AS prev
  9          FROM   t)
 10  GROUP BY grp
 11  CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND grp = PRIOR grp
 12  START WITH curr = 1;

GRP COMMAND
--- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ONE <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>,<message1>MESSAGE</message1>,<message2>MESSAGE</message2>
TWO <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>,<message2>MESSAGE</message2>,<message9>MESSAGE</message9>

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, i encountered this error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" during execution. Is LISTAGG supported in Oracle10g?

Comment: Is there any other solution to concatenate in Oracle10g? @LalitKumarB

Comment: Ok, see the updated answer. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH `.

Comment: Once again, Thank you for the swift response. :)

Comment: @jamesleeroyDator You're welcome! Glad I could help you with your second topic ;-)